# El html no muestra la imagen recogida desde la api

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, html5, api

estoy haciendo una aplicación con la  pokeapi. Quiero que aparezca la imagen del pokemon dentro de un div. Al recoger los datos en formato json la url de la imagen la recoge sin problemas. Pero al poner la etiqueta img dentro del div con el inner html no aparece la imagen. Pero hago un console.log de la variable que contiene la url y aparece la url completa.
[image: Aparece la url de la imagen en la consola]

En cambio al ver el inspeccionar elementos aparece la etiqueta img pero la url y el alt aparecen vacíos.
[image: La url aparece vacía]

Este es el código que tengo ahora mismo

```
let llamada = () => {
    let post_it = document.getElementsByClassName("post-it");
    let url;
    let nombre;
    
    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + random())
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        url = data.sprites.front_default;
        nombre = data.species.name;

        console.log(url)

        post_it.innerHTML = "<img src='" + url + "' alt='" + nombre + "'/>";
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tan solo tienes un elemento con clase post-it mejor que cambies esto:

```
let post_it = document.getElementsByClassName("post-it");
```

por esto:

```
let post_it = document.querySelector(".post-it");
```

o por esto:

```
let post_it = document.getElementsByClassName("post-it")[0];
```

pues [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) devuelve una colección de elementos similar a un array.

Sin embargo, si tienes varios divs con esa clase y quieres que todos hagan el cambio, entonces puedes cambiar esto:

```
post_it.innerHTML = "<img src='" + url + "' alt='" + nombre + "'/>";
```

por esto:

```
for(let i = 0; i < post_it.length; i++) {
  post_it[i].innerHTML = "<img src='" + url + "' alt='" + nombre + "'/>"
}
```